# PHP quotation marks and associative arrays: what style adheres to Zend Standard?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, coding-style, standards

We use the Zend framework coding standard (although we don't use Zend framework itself).
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

What's the preferred style of using associative array values within a string? As far as I can see there are three ways of doing this (and the coding standards don't make it clear which is stylistically preferable).

1) My Preferred option.

```
echo "Cool Story $family[bro]";
```

2) Some of my colleagues preferred option.

```
echo "Cool Story {$family['bro']}";
```

3) We tend not to do this.

```
echo 'Cool Story ' . $family['bro'];
```

Is either of these actually preferred by the Zend Project? If not, what do you use and why.

**edit:** In response to the votes to close, here is the 'real question'... Are there specific examples from within the Zend framework code, that hint at an internal standard that is not explicitly documented in the standards?

Comment: Since the "coding standards doesn't make it clear which is stylistically preferable" you have to come to an agreement with your developers on your own. We cannot tell you more than what is given in the standard itself.

Comment: Shouldn't it be defined within the standards then? I guess we could stand on the shoulders of those standards and create our own. I find that without standards some devs get into edit wars (usually unintentionally) in trying to enforce their preferred syntax

Comment: well, maybe it should, but it isnt. so, you can now either contact the zf guys asking them to do that or you can simply sit together and decide how you want to use it in your project. then write a phpcs rule for it and be done with it.

Comment: The first is unwanted and will generate a notice. (something like "unfound constant (?), interpreted as string". `bro` is nothing if not a defined constant -> you should use `'bro'` or `"bro"` between the `[]`. The other two are taste afaik.

Comment: @Nanne +3 upvoters No - the top version works fine. Try it (it doesn't generate a notice - I develop with all errors being output). I'm guessing this is why some of my colleagues don't use this syntax (they don't know that it _is_ valid)... edit: seriously stop upvoting that comment - it's NOT correct

Comment: @Gordon. Thanks - given your credentials I'm sure you know what you're talking about. We'll just write our own standards.

Comment: Your preferred option is the only one which is definitely wrong. This syntax (ie skipping the quotes in an array keyname) is deprecated due to the potential for ambiguity. The other two are both equally correct, and can be used according to preference and the situation at hand. I generally prefer (2), but there are times when (3) is better. But you should definitely *not* be using (1).

Comment: @Spudley Hi, do you have a link (source) to where this notation is deprecated? It would solve this argument very easily for me!

Comment: Obviously I tried it, I'm not making this stuff up you know. "it works fine" is not the problem. It's incorrect syntax however you look at it. Maybe your PHP version doens't generate those notices yet, but in a new version you WILL get `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant bro - assumed 'bro'`. As said, it doens't matter if you see a notice or not, it is incorrect syntax and should not be used. A string (what the key is in an associated array) is defined as a series characters between quotes (etc). Without they are a constant.

Comment: Guys, just have a look at http://codepad.viper-7.com/lIUQxQ and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-77

Comment: @Nanne O.K, I admit i'm not running 5.3 yet in all environments. I'll update my version of PHP. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: subtle edit btw, with that "stop upvoting".

Comment: @Nanne - not that subtle (I used the word edit!) :-)

Comment: @kissmyface - The PHP manual has a discussion of this topic here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. Look for the section entitled "Array do's and don'ts"; it very clearly discusses why this syntax works but why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Gordon Sorry, I've changed my mind - both the example you posted AND the documentation back up my version. I'm not going to continue to argue here, but thanks for all your input. No notice is issued when using the array as I've used it AND from the php.net docs.... // The following is okay, as it's inside a string. Constants are not looked for
// within strings, so no E_NOTICE occurs here
print "Hello $arr[fruit]";      // Hello apple

Comment: @Spudley yes (ive already linked that above), but if you follow the third link to the string interpolation examples, you will see that they use an assoc key without quotes in the manual as well. And since it doesnt raise a notice I guess all of you are right. No need to fight over it.

Comment: There's also another discussion in the PHP manaul here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php which covers why curly braces are preferred even when you're not using an array. By the way, the `{}` syntax was introduced as far back as PHP4, precicely because of the issues caused by having free-floating variables in a string, so it's not exactly new.